# Having difficulties with list in STL

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

Given an array, copy the elements in vector and list, using the single iterator method of erase delete even numbers from vector and odd numbers from list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int ia[] = {0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,55,89};
    int len = sizeof(ia) / sizeof(ia[0]);
  
    // making vector and list
    vector<int> vec;
    list<int> lst;
    for(int i=0; i!=len; i++){
        vec.push_back(ia[i]);
        lst.push_back(ia[i]);
    }
    // simple printing
    cout<<"Vector: "<<endl;
    for(auto ele: vec)
        cout<<ele<<" ";

    cout<<"\nList: "<<endl;
    for(auto ele: lst)
        cout<<ele<<" ";

    // vector containing only odd numbers
    // list containing only even numbers
    vector<int>::iterator iv = vec.begin();
    list<int>::iterator il = lst.begin();

    for(; iv!=vec.end(), il!=lst.end(); iv++, il++){     
        if((*iv % 2) == 0){
            int temp = *iv;  
            vector<int>::iterator iter =  find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), temp);        
            if(iter != vec.end())                
                vec.erase(iter);
        }
        else if((*il % 2) == 1){
            int temp = *il;
            list<int>::iterator iter = find(lst.begin(), lst.end(), temp);
            if(iter != lst.end())
                lst.erase(iter);
        }
    }
    
    // simple printing
    cout<<"\n\nNew Vector containing odd numbers: "<<endl;
    for(auto ele: vec)
        cout<<ele<<" ";

    cout<<"\nNew List containing even numbers: "<<endl;
    for(auto ele: lst)
        cout<<ele<<" ";    

}
```

After running the abouve code it gives a segmentation fault, but if i comment out the list logic in for loop, the program runs fine (expect the deletion of odd elemnts from list)

below is the output after commenting out the list in for loop

```
Vector: 
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 55 89 
List: 
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 55 89 

New Vector containing odd numbers: 
1 1 3 5 13 21 55 89 
New List containing even numbers:  
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 55 89
```

Comment: `iv!=vec.end(), il!=lst.end()` means: evaluate `iv!=vec.end()`, drop the result and then use `il!=lst.end()`... Also why use a single loop for both containers? Those could have different lengths resuling in UB when moving the iterator past the end iterator of the corresponding collection.

Comment: Doing `vec.erase(iter);` when you're iterating over `vec` is a usually not a good idea. It could invalidate the iterator `iv` so it no longer will work in the condition `iv!=vec.end()`.

Comment: Btw: the ideomatic way of accomplishing this simply moves the elements from the containers and erases from the end of the list: [`vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [=](int i) { return (i % 2) ==0; }), vec.end());`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

Comment: I think you are meant to write two loops, one for the list and one for the vector, not one combined loop for both.

Comment: Your code might invalidate the iterators in the loop when it mutates the container, the `il` iterator is certainly invalidated when `erase` what it points to.  Your code crashes on my machine.  Enable warnings, fix warnings.

Comment: You already have the iterators to the relevant elements; they are `iv` and `il`. There is no point in using `find` to get more iterators to the same elements. There is also no point in checking whether you found `temp`, since you got it by dereferencing an iterator just a couple of lines earlier.

Answer (score 0):

As always, there are many different potential solutions:

For example, we could use ready to use functions from the algorithm library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {

    int ia[] = { 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,55,89 };

    // making vector and list
    std::vector<int> vec{ std::begin(ia),std::end(ia) };
    std::list<int> lst { std::begin(ia),std::end(ia) }; ;

    // simple printing
    std::cout << "Vector:\n";
    for (auto ele : vec) std::cout << ele << ' ';

    std::cout << "\nList:\n";
    for (auto ele : lst) std::cout << ele << ' ';

    // vector containing only odd numbers
    vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int i) {return !(i % 2); }), vec.end());
    // list containing only even numbers
    lst.erase(std::remove_if(lst.begin(), lst.end(), [](int i) {return i % 2; }), lst.end());

    // simple printing
    std::cout << "\n\nNew Vector containing odd numbers:\n";
    for (auto ele : vec)  std::cout << ele << ' ';

    std::cout << "\nNew List containing even numbers:\n";
    for (auto ele : lst) std::cout << ele << ' ';
}
```

In C++20 there is also an `erase_if` function.

You can do it also by iteratirng over pointers. But then you need to be careful. Of course, if you erase an element, the iterator pointing to it, will be invalidated.

But luckily the `erase` function will return an `iterator` to the next element.

Solution based on this idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {

    int ia[] = { 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,55,89 };

    // making vector and list
    std::vector<int> vec{ std::begin(ia),std::end(ia) };
    std::list<int> lst{ std::begin(ia),std::end(ia) }; ;

    // simple printing
    std::cout << "Vector:\n";
    for (auto ele : vec) std::cout << ele << ' ';

    std::cout << "\nList:\n";
    for (auto ele : lst) std::cout << ele << ' ';

    // vector containing only odd numbers
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end();     ) {
        if (*it % 2 == 0)
            it = vec.erase(it);
        else
            ++it;
    }
    // list containing only even numbers
    // Erase all even numbers
    for (std::list<int>::iterator it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end();    )    {
        if (*it % 2 == 1)
            it = lst.erase(it);
        else
            ++it;
    }
    // simple printing
    std::cout << "\n\nNew Vector containing odd numbers:\n";
    for (auto ele : vec)  std::cout << ele << ' ';

    std::cout << "\nNew List containing even numbers:\n";
    for (auto ele : lst) std::cout << ele << ' ';
}
```